# When quotient ring is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $K = \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$. For what values of $a$ quotient ring $K[x]/\left<x^2 + a\right>$ is a field?

I tried to use the bruteforce method here.

Since we are quotienting by $\left<x^2 + a\right>$ all our elements can be represented as : $a_0 + a_1 \cdot x$.

Initially I assumed $a_1 = 0$. So I'm considering the elements with non-zero $a_0$ like $1, 2, 3,4,5,6$. Let $a_0\cdot(p_0 + p_1\cdot x) = a_0 \cdot p_0 + a_0 \cdot p_1 \cdot x = 1$. I can take $p_1 = 0$, so it only lasts $a_0 \cdot p_0 = 1$ and I checked that $\forall a_0\ \exists p_0 \ | a_0 \cdot p_0 = 0$. So this case gives me no information about my $a$.

Then I considered the case when $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 \neq 0$.

$1 = a_1x(p_0 + p_1x)  = a_1p_0x + a_1p_1x^2$. I know that $x^2 = -a \Rightarrow a_1p_0x + a_1p_1(-a)$. As before I can let $p_0 = 0$ and only deal with $a_1p_1(-a) = 1$. And here I got stuck, because I don't how to choose $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotient ring is a field, exactly when the polynomial is irreducible.  In this case, since the polynomial is of degree 2, it is irreducible exactly when it has no roots.  Hence, all you need to do is determine which polynomials $x^2+a$ have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$, by simply evaluating at all seven values.  There are at most 49 things to check.

For example, $a=0$ has a root, namely $x=0$.

Comment: The squares mod 7 are $0,1,4,2,$ and $x^2 +a$ has a root iff $-a$ is a square. So the failing $a$'s are $-0, -1, -4, -2 \equiv 0,6,3,5$

Answer (score 9):

[Just to add to vadim123's answer:]
\begin{align}
K[x]\left/\langle x^2+a\rangle\right.&\text{ is a field }\\
\Longleftrightarrow K[x]\left/\langle x^2+a\rangle\right.&\text{ has no proper ideals}\\
\Longleftrightarrow \langle x^2+a\rangle&\text{ is a maximal ideal}\\
\Longleftrightarrow x^2+a&\text{ is irreducible}
\end{align}